# What's the meaning of the phrase "You seem med"?

Tags: slang, informal-language

During an online game, one of the opposing players said "You seem med", and when I asked what "med" was, the response was "It's a chav slang term". Then player logged out.

I googled the phrase, but I can't find a definition in the usual online slang dictionaries. Any suggestions?

My guesses
1) Medicated? (as in sedated)
2) Mad (crazy, under the influence of drugs?)

Comment: Well, I did learn that [chav is a BrE pejorative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chav).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a typo for "*mad*" which makes a lot of sense in your context. Consider the common online phrase: "You mad bro?" ... or ... "You're all mad lol."
Both of these are kind of insults.  So if he typo-ed while insulting you and you asked him about it, then he blamed it on a classist pejorative label and logged out (chav = council-housed and violent)... then it would all fit together.

Or it could be a spelling of "*mad*" meant to sound like it was spoken with an accent. Or maybe it really is some slang term. I would guess meaning "medicated".

Comment: The Wikipedia description of "chav" says that they've incorporated Jamaican patois into their slang, so the misspelling could be deliberate. The article also says that  "council-housed and violent" is a bit of folk etymology and was probably made up after the word was already being used.

Comment: This definition of *chav* came to me from a player of an online game using slang, so I figure it's the best one for OP's scenario.  Of course, with words like *folk* and *probably*, the author really doesn't know either way. Thanks for the patois clue, that points towards "mad".

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's "**mad**" and a typo happened. 
And when the meaning of mad is replaced, it is kinda meaningful. 
But for med, there no meaning but **MEd** = **Master of Education**. 
I'd consider it as the word **mad**.